# Returning different response codes under MVC2 POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, post, header, http-response-codes

I am developing a REST API using MVC2.

When handling a POST request in an Action method, am supposed to populate various custom Response headers with values, and also set specific HTTP response codes.

Since this is a POST request, I am returning an EmptyResult.

When I call against the site, I can see that the custom headers are getting populated, but the response code (which I have set using Response.StatusCode = ...) is ignored, and I always get 200.

My tech lead has suggested using a HTTPException to get the Response code, but I regard this as the wrong apprach. I've tried it anyway, and as I suspected, the response code is write, but everything else (my custom Response Headers) is screwed up.

Following a similar thread on StackOverflow, I have tried to write my own subclass of ActionResult to handle this, but again - I just get 200s back.

The class, for those interested, is here:

```
Public Class HttpStatusCodeActionResult : Inherits ActionResult

#Region "Data Members"
    Private mintStatusCode As Integer = 0
    Private mstrStatusDescription As String = ""
#End Region
    Public Sub New(ByVal vintStatusCode As Integer, ByVal vstrStatusDescription As String)
        mintStatusCode = vintStatusCode
        mstrStatusDescription = vstrStatusDescription
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub ExecuteResult(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext)
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = mintStatusCode
        If mstrStatusDescription <> "" Then
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = mstrStatusDescription
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Does anyone have any idea what the correct approach might be to being able to specify the response code AND return my custom headers? This only seems to be POST requests by the way - GET requests seem to work fine...

Cheers in anticipation,

Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it works with get you can redirect to another action after handling post and there you can set the repspose header

Comment: Cheers Muhammad. Can you explain why you would redirect please? (I'm not a MVC guru...). I would have thought that once I redirect to a different action method, I would lose the Response headers I have already created?

Comment: you can keep an action for setting your headers and you can set all your headers after you have handled the post and reached that action through a redirect. this suggestion in meant to be a workaround of the situation.

Comment: So the HTTP response would keep the headers even through we move to a new action result? Hang on - giving it a whirl...

Comment: +1 for a valiant try, but using an action redirect will actually send back a 302 response to the client. If the client were a browser that might not matter so much, but in this case the client is someone else's code... Can't go with I'm afraid...

Comment: Actually, I'm going to accept that answer, as it does answer the question I asked - it's not your fault that my circumstances mean I can't use it. If anyone else has a suggestion to offer though, feel free...